# Is it possible to run a webserver with apache openwhisk?

Tags: webserver, openwhisk

I'm working on a project in my University, and we want to use an Apache OpenWhisk service for our student projects. I already set up the OpenWhisk service and add some components like Java, NodeJS and Python, everything works fine. My next step is to set up a webserver, so our students can use this instances to publish their websites (written in HTML, PHP, Java Script). I have already searched for this topic but don't found anything.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this and it depends on how far you want to go in the serverless direction.

For example this repo https://github.com/jthomas/express_example is a way to package an existing web server inside a function. This is another variation on the same https://github.com/IBM/expressjs-openwhisk.

If you want the students to implement a serverless web application from scratch, then generally every API end point becomes a function using **web actions** https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/webactions.md.

You can use web actions to also serve static content (html, js, css) by inlining those files and returning them as part of the function result. This is not ideal and should be done from a CDN instead. OpenWhisk itself does not offer object storage/CDN support but you can use S3 or Google buckets to accomplish the same.

Some serverless platforms like [Netlify](https://netlify.com) or [Nimbella](https://nimbella.com/resources/static-assets) might be suitable. The latter provides an integrated CDN + OpenWhisk to implement entire web applications including JAMstack.